# Datagrid Virtualization does not work properly when IsSelected property is set programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I'm working with datagrid that will load more than a thousand items so I enabled virtualization. When I tried to select all using the Datagrid.SelectAll() in code behind, the selection works fine. But when I change the IsSelected property programatically of the hidden items, the items are not updated when I scroll down.

Steps using SelectAll():

1. Initially all the items are selected using SelectAll() in code behind.
2. I selected 1 row.
3. All other items will be unselected except the one selected.

Steps using programatically updating IsSelected property to true:

1. Initially all the items are selected by programatically updating each item property IsSelected=true.
2. I selected 1 row.
3. Visible items are deselected except the currently selected row. But when I scroll down, the hidden items are still selected.

How can I update the IsSelected property of the hidden items?

Comment: Is not it a mistake in your description? Does DataGrid.Select**All()** selects only some specific row?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated my issue. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to unselect all rows before selecting the specific one? Like `dataGridView.ClearSelection()`; As far as I know, with `row.IsSelected` you can select any number of rows. It will not unselect previously selected rows: `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) rows[i].isSelected = true` will select all 10 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by handling the hidden items on selection change.This is implemented using MVVM pattern.

```
        private void HandleContentSelection(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e == null) return;

            var dataGrid = e.Source as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid == null) return;

            #region Update Grid Selection

            if (e.AddedItems != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.AddedItems.Cast<IContent>())
                {
                    if (!item.IsSelected)
                    {
                        item.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.RemovedItems != null)
            {
                _contentsToBeUnselected.Clear();

                // Handle Multiple selection
                // Set hidden items IsSelected property to false
                if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 0 && (e.AddedItems == null || e.AddedItems.Count == 0) && e.RemovedItems.Count > 1)
                {
                    foreach (var content in dataGrid.Items.Cast<IContent>())
                    {
                        if (!dataGrid.SelectedItems.Contains(content))
                        {
                            _contentsToBeUnselected.Add(content);
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Handle Unselect All
                // Set hidden items IsSelected property to false
                else if (dataGrid.SelectedItems.Count == 0 && (e.AddedItems == null || e.AddedItems.Count == 0))
                {
                    _contentsToBeUnselected.AddRange(dataGrid.Items.Cast<IContent>());
                }
                else
                {
                    _contentsToBeUnselected.AddRange(e.RemovedItems.Cast<IContent>());
                }

                foreach (var item in _contentsToBeUnselected)
                {
                    if (item.IsSelected)
                    {
                        // if bound data item still is selected, fix this
                        item.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            e.Handled = true;

            #endregion

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `DataGrid.UnselectAllCells();`